# Proper name for reference tables in OLTP

Tags: naming-convention

I know this might be a silly question. But I really appreciate accepting and answering this question.

When I have an OLTP database with some big tables like orders and items. I have other tables (similar to dimension tables in OLAP) where we store reference values, such as: currency, city, category.

What is the proper name for those reference tables? Can we still call them dimension tables in OLTP or do they have their own generic name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **reference table** generally loosely fits the definition of a **dimension table** or sometimes you'll hear the less formal term **enum table** for **reference tables** with a unique set of values. I think it's generally fair to use all three terms interchangeably.

Generally when your schema follows the **Star Schema** or **Snowflake Schema**, you reference the tables by either the terms **fact tables** for your measured quantitative values and **dimension tables** for your qualitative values.